# Are seasonal Unusual hats limited to seasonal effects?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'd like some clarification on some things Unusual hat related.

Some Unusual effects are "Halloween themed", for ex. Secret to Everybody, Stormy 13th, Knifestorm, etc.

Some Unusual hats are "Halloween themed", for ex., Crone's Dome, Wraith Wrap

Are hats and effects season exclusive? Meaning, can I only get a Halloween effect during Halloween? Or does it require a certain crate? Is it based on contents of crate? Is it a specific period of full moon cycle?

Some clarification would help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Halloween unusual effects**, such as cauldron bubbles or knifestorm, *can only be unboxed around late October/early November*. Halloween unusual effects are not limited to halloween hats (e.g. you can get a Stormy 13th hour [German Gonzila](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/German_Gonzila)). Unusual Halloween effects can be unboxed from any crate; in fact, I believe they are the only effects unboxed during this limited time.

**Halloween-themed hats**, such as [Crone's dome](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crone%27s_Dome) or the [Executioner](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Executioner), can be unboxed as unusuals at any time of the year. However, they will only have standard unusual effects (smoking, bubbling, green energy, etc).

Comment: If you could clarify, for Halloween hats, I mean hats that were released during Halloween, but could have Unusual particles attached (For example, Cloudy Moon Crone's Dome).  Are those Unusual hats limited to a certain time period, or can they be found anytime?

Comment: Updated answer to clarify. To answer your example, you can get a Cloudy Moon Crone's Dome any time of the year.

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Particle_effects#Unusual_effects):

> 4 more Halloween only effects were added with the Very Scary Halloween
>   Special, and another 5 with the Spectral Halloween Special. Those can
>   only be obtained during Halloween events.

Comment: So what are "Halloween" events. Does that mean that it has to be during October? Or can it be on any server running Halloween maps? Also, this doesn't help for hats that are Halloween exclusive

Comment: The server you are on does not affect what items will be dropped or obtained from crates. "Halloween event" refers to the annual Scream Fortress event (or whatever name they happen to use that year). I do believe that Halloween hats only drop at this time, though I could only find hard evidence for the Halloween effects.